# Use of as if in my question

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, gerunds

(I picked A but according to my book correct answer is B , why can't l use A ? )

Question is : We were not fortunate enough to attend a tea company while in japan,but we_____as if we____the guests of the Japanese as we wandered the streets of Tokyo.

A-felt/were

B-were feeling/Had been

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are correct. Perhaps your book provides more context enabling us to choose between the two options. "A" is reporting an event. "B" describes experiencing the event. "A" is past tense - "something happened." "B" is more continuous - it's describing the event as it was happening at the time.

Comment: All context  given is  that

Comment: @mustafaatmaca - Then I agree with you. Either "A" or "B" are correct English. One is as likely to be used as the other. They do carry slightly different connotations. That is, a given person might consistently pick one form over the other to match their writing style.

Comment: I found out answer  :The past perfect subjunctive after as if / as though is used to refer to an unreal past situation.